# Construir menu de sidebar dinamicamente cno vue 3 y vue-router

Tags: javascript, vue3, vue-router

Estoy tratando de construir un menu de tres niveles de forma dinámica por medio de un json y recorrerlo con v-for para construirlo, solo el tercer nivel tiene que tener link, para eso uso el `<router-link to="">`, para el primer y segundo nivel solo es un `<a href="#">` normal, y recorro el json con v-for:

```
<ul class="sidebar-elements">
 <li class="parent" v-for="(modules, moduleName) in menu"> <!-- Primer nivel -->
  <a href="#">{{ moduleName }}</a>
  <ul class="sub-menu">
   <li class="parent" v-for="(transactions, transactionName) in modules"> <!-- Segundo nivel -->
    <a href="#">{{ transactionName }}</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu" v-for="(sub, subTransactionName) in transactions"> <!-- Tercer nivel -->
     <li>
      <router-link :to="{name: sub.subLink}">{{ subTransactionName }}</router-link>
     </li>
    </ul>
   </li> 
  </ul>
 </li>
</ul>

<script>
import { apipoint } from '@/logic/constants'
export default {

setup(){

  const menu = ref({})

  const get_main_menu = async () => {
    const { data } = await apipoint.post('get-main-menu')
    menu.value = data
    console.log(menu.value)
  }

  get_main_menu()

  return {
    menu
  }

}

}
```

El json con el cual construyo el menú lo obtengo con una petición por medio de una api con axios, el problema se da cuando doy click para expandir los menus, el router de vue toma como si fuera la ruta "/" y no abre el menu, simplemente me lleva a la página de inicio con cualquiera de los niveles primero y segundo, como si todos tuvieran router-link, utilizo composition api, alguna idea de como pueda solucionarlo?

Comment: ¿Y si quitas el `href` de las <a> para probar?  Lo digo porque seguramente son ellos los que te llevan alli... luego ya te plantearas que hacer, pero de momento prueba eso para confirmarlo.

Comment: Ya los quité, pero sigue igual, lo único diferente es el cursos se pone como si fuera un simple texto y no la mano como una opción del menú.

Comment: Pero curiosamente pongo el json directo como valor en la variable de menú y funciona a la perfección, no se si sea un problema con lo asincrono.